# ghci configuration file

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm using ghci 6.8.2 on Ubuntu. Does ghci use a configuration file where we can do some initial setup?. E.g.: `:set prompt "ghci> "`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Have you tried adding `:set prompt "ghci> "` to [~/.ghci](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.8.2/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html)?

Comment: Sorry for such a basic question, but I can't understand: What is the full name of the .ghci file? And where exactly to put that file? I tried putting this file in the neighbourhood of a haskell code file, but the ghci didn't seem to read that .ghci file.

Comment: In Windows, you put the file in your user directory. E.g. `C:\Users\YourUsername\`.

Answer (score 47):

Having applied @hvr's answer I got the following warning:

```
*** WARNING: ~/.ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
```

The solution is `chmod g-w ~/.ghci`.

Answer (score 1):

In my `~/.ghci` configuration file. I have the following line:

`:set prompt "\ESC[0;34m\STX%s\n\ESC[1;31m\STXλ> \ESC[m\STX"`

And here is how my `ghci` prompt looks like:

https://asciinema.org/a/Tpk5430dPqCRN0cFqi1ucaCb8

In that config file, I temporarily commented out `:set +m`.

Comment: That nice lambda doesn't work for me in ghci, while it does work in my terminal :/

Comment: adding it to `~/.ghci` did absolutely nothing for me - GHCi says `Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/<user>/.ghci` but the prompt didn't change :/

Answer (score 0):

In [@truthadjustr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109980/208273) the prelude comes every time you run any command.

`:set prompt "\ESC[1;31m\STXλ> \ESC[m\STX"`

This command solves the problem.

Comment: that was his goal - to still show the packages - a feature, not a bug