# Can I use template haskell to define missing functions?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, stm

I've got a situation where I need to compile some Haskell code on different machines.
At least one of these machines has a rather old version of [Control.Concurrent.STM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.1.1.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html), that doesn't know `modifyTVar`. My current workaround is to copy the code for modifyTVar from a [newer version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html) of the package. This got me wondering, if it would be possible to use template Haskell to check if a function is already defined and only define it, if it's missing. I'm aware that the proper solution would probably be to get more recent packages, but the situation got me curious.

Comment: Why not just use CPP (checking the version of the `stm` package)?

Comment: I wasn't aware this would have been an option. I tried using ``#ifdef``, but kinda failed with it. Given my rather small knowledge of that topic I'm also not sure how to check a package version with it.

Comment: I added an answer with the details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be possible as follows. First a helper module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module AddFn where

import Language.Haskell.TH

-- | Add a function if it doesn't exist.
addFn :: String -> Q [Dec] -> Q [Dec]
addFn name decl = do
    r <- lookupValueName name
    case r of
        Just l -> return []
        Nothing -> report False ("adding missing " ++ name) >> decl
```

and use it as in

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import AddFn
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

$(addFn "mapM"
    [d| mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
        mapM = T.mapM
    |])

$(addFn "mapM1"
    [d| mapM1 :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
        mapM1 = T.mapM
    |])
```

The drawback is that it's using `lookupValueName`, which is only in the recent versions of TH, so when dealing with old installations, this probably won't help. Perhaps a possible solution would be to instead call `reify` on a given name, and use `recover` to handle the case when the name is missing.

**Update:** The version using `reify` instead of `lookupValueName` works:

```
-- | Add a function if it doesn't exist.
addFn :: String -> Q [Dec] -> Q [Dec]
addFn name decl = recover decl (reify (mkName name) >> return [])
```

Answer (score 3):

Template Haskell is somewhat overkill for this - you can use `CPP` instead, using the `MIN_VERSION` macros that Cabal will define:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

#if MIN_VERSION_stm(2, 3, 0)
-- nothing
#else
modifyTVar = ...
#endif
```

Comment: I've got this running now, but I had to make two small adjustments, to get it working nicely with ghci as well. It was necessary to get ghci to include the cabal_macros.h. To do this I followed instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622537/running-ghci-on-a-module-that-needs-language-cpp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388261/ghci-configuration-file

Comment: With recent cabals, I think you can just use `cabal repl`